# Primay key in Phoenix returns Null when decleared as bigint

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix, squirrel-sql

I am using Phoenix to run SQL on my HBase, but when I try bigint for primary key it returns NULL for that columns in select but varchar return correct result

Answer (score 1):

This is plainly because the primary key in Hbase/Phoenix is stored as an integer, which by definition can be 0,1,-1. If it is 0, it is nullable which a primary key cannot be. Hence, we need to keep it as a VARCHAR.